# Find volume of solid bounded by given surfaces. $z=a+x,z=-a-x,x^2+y^2=a^2$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry, volume, multiple-integral

Find volume of solid bounded by given surfaces.

$$z=a+x, \qquad z=-a-x, \qquad x^2+y^2=a^2$$

[image]

This is the solid. We can find volume of solid that has positive $z$ value and multiply by $2$. And for finding volume of that solid I thought doing double integral where domain is circle and function is that ellipse. $\int_{-a}^a dy \int_{-a}^a f(x,y)dx$. Where $f(x,y)$ is intersection of plane $z=a+x$ and $x^2+y^2=a^2$. Is my thinking right? When I want to find intersection I  substitute $x=z-a$ into   $x^2+y^2=a^2$ I get $z=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-y^2}}{2}$ which when I graph does not look like ellipse. Can you help?

Comment: When substituting $x=z-a$ into $x^2+y^2=a^2$ I get $z=a\pm\sqrt{a^2-y^2}$, which does look as an ellipse to me.

Comment: @Patricio Ok how continue from that?

Comment: If you cut solid body by plane $z=0$ and move cut parts you can combine them into whole cylinder with $r=a$ and $h=2a$

Answer (score 1):

In cylindrical coordinates, the cutting plane for $z>0$ is  $z=a+r\cos \theta$. The volume is then
$$V =2 \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a z\  rdr d\theta =2\pi a^3
$$
Note that, geometrically, the two symmetric parts above/below the $xy$-plane configures to a regular cylinder of cross-section area $\pi a^2 $ and height $2a$, hence the volume $2\pi a^3$.

Comment: That seems to be missing the part of the body under the $\;xy\,-$ plane...

Comment: @DonAntonio Isn't that why the factor of $2$ is there? Since the body is symmetric about the $z$-axis, the volume will just be $2$ times the volume of the upper half.

Comment: @Lorago You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Intersection of planes is a line given by, $z = a + x = - a - x \implies x = - a, z = 0$
At intersection with the cylinder, $(-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2 \implies y = 0$

So, both planes and the cylinder intersect at a single point $(-a, 0, 0)$. That means the projection of the region in xy-plane is circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2, z = 0$

The integral to find volume is given by,

$ \displaystyle V = \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2} 2 |a + x| ~ dx ~ dy$

Note that if $a \lt 0, a + x $ is always negative (or zero) over the region and if $a \gt 0, a + x$ is always non-negative over the region.

Now as $x$ is an odd function, $[f(-x) = - f(x)]$, and the region is symmetric to yz plane, its integral over $x \gt 0$ will cancel out the integral over $x \lt 0$.

So, $ \displaystyle V = 2 |a| \iint_{x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2}  dx ~ dy = 2 \pi |a|^3$

Comment: In the  last part how you get $|a|$ at the beginning?

Comment: Take either case. Say $a$ is positive then the integrand is $(a + x)$ and if $a$ is negative then the integrand is $(- a - x)$. Integral of $x$ is zero as I explained. That leads to $a$ if $a$ is positive and $-a $ if $a$ is negative. So, I am writing $|a|$

Comment: Can you please also say which region is symmetric to yz plane?

Comment: the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2$ or the projection of the region in xy plane, which is circle $x^2 + y^2 \leq a^2, z = 0$

Comment: A circle centered at the origin is symmetric to y-axis, i.e. the region to its right and to its left